# Asciidoc Maven Build PDF links not Working

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am using the asciidoctor-maven-plugin to create a PDF User Guide from asciidoc source files.

I use the following format for cross references within the adoc files:

```
link:overview/name_of_file.adoc[Link name]
```

But the link is rendered as follows in the PDF:

```
file:///<local path>/overview/name_of_file.adoc
```

That is, the links the don't work. How to generate working links in the PDF (but also retain an .adoc link format that works in the source file for use in bitbucket)?

Output is one PDF

Comment: Is your output one pdf? or do you create multiple pdfs?

Comment: @EhmKah: One PDF